# Find nodes that has a particular relationship with the input node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have nodes with name and id property. These nodes have friend relationship with other nodes. Like {John}-[Friend]->{Paul},{John}-[Friend]->{Jose},{Jose}-[Friend]->{Paul}

Creating User

```
session.run( "CREATE (a:User {name: {name}, id: {id}})",
            parameters( "name", name, "id", id ) );
```

Creating Relationships

```
session.run("MATCH (a:User),(b:User) WHERE a.id = {node1} AND b.id = {node2} CREATE (a)-[r:FRIENDS]->(b)",
            parameters( "node1", id1, "node2", id2 ) );
```

Now I am looking for query John's friend, which should list me paul and jose. How do i do that ? Tried the below and getting empty result. Not able to figure out why

```
session.run("MATCH (a:User{id:{id}})<-[:FRIEND]-(actor) RETURN a.id",
            parameters( "id", user ) );
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have your read through the [developer's manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/)? This is basic query functionality that is well explained in the documentation: match on your start node with the desired pattern, return the parts of the pattern that you're interested in. What have you tried so far in your attempts to query?

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon . Updated the question with my approach. Yeah looks basic like a select query but kinda feeling stuck. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you're using the same relationship type as you did when the relationship was created. In your creation query, you create a :FRIENDS relationship, but in your subsequent query, you are looking for a :FRIEND relationship. You'll need to make sure you're being consistent.

Also, you'll want to make sure you're returning the parameters from the correct variables in your match.

In your query, `a` is your start node, since you're supplying the id of that node, but you're returning the id of the same node. I think you mean to return `actor.id`, which references the variable on the other side of the match.

Another thing to keep in mind is relationship direction. All relationships in Neo4j have a direction, but there are many queries where you either do not care what direction the relationship is in, or you don't know if it goes one direction or another. Your :FRIENDS relationship is a prime example, since when you query for if two users are friends, you won't know or care about the direction, so you can leave the directional arrow out of your query.

Try this:

```
session.run("MATCH (a:User{id:{id}})-[:FRIENDS]-(actor) RETURN actor.id",
        parameters( "id", user ) );
```